# django: unable to save new user

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a view that shows a form for creating a new user.
Next are the template I'm using, urls.py and the code attempts at views.py and forms.py.

```
user_form.html

    <form action="{% url 'app:register' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
    </form>
```

```
urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('newuser/',views.NewUser.as_view(), name='newuser'),
    ...
]
```

##### First attempt:

```
views.py

class NewUser(generic.CreateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['username','email','password']
    template_name = 'app/user_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('register')
```

This one didn't return errors, but was unable to save the new user data.

##### Second try involved creating a form for the occasion:

```
forms.py

class NewUserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.PasswordInput()

views.py

class NewUser(generic.CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = NewUserForm
    template_name = 'app/user_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('register')
```

This one returned an error: `TypeError at /newuser/ BaseForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'`

##### Third:

```
forms.py

class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password']

views.py

class NewUser(generic.CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = NewUserForm
    template_name = 'app/user_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cadastro')
```

Can't save a new User instance either.
I've also noticed that the `model = User` line in this last try can be removed.

I'm using the `User.objects.all()` query in the terminal and the admin page to check for new users.

What am I not doing?

Comment: Where is urls.py?

Comment: @eisanahardani Just added it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should make the POST request to the `newuser` view, so:

```
<form action="{% url 'app:newuser' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

You can however not use a simple `ModelForm`: passwords in Django are hashed and the `ModelForm` will *not* do that, or at least not automatically.

You can make use of the [**`UserCreationForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) to do the hashing properly, this field also uses *two* password fields which will be validated.

If you want to implement a custom `ModelForm`, then you will need to implement the password hashing functionality in the model form:

```
class NewUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

and then plug this into the `CreateView` with:

```
class NewUserView(generic.CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = NewUserForm
    template_name = 'app/user_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('cadastro')
```

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `NewUserView`, instead of <s>`NewUser`</s>.

Comment: Let me see if I get it: there's is no saving user without performing password hashing first, and the UserCreationForm helps with it.  About `app:newuser`, must the form then post to its own url?

Comment: @101is5: it will save the user regardless whether hashing is performed, but without hashing, the password is "unusable". But the form should submit to its own URL, otherwise the `CreateView` will not handle the POST request.

Comment: Oh, another thing: a User's instance may contain an email field. On the other hand UserCreationForm doesn't have it. How to include it after the password hashing process?

Comment: @101is5: just add it to the `fields = ...` in the `ModelForm`.

Comment: Is it(unusable password) why a new User won't show in a new Users.objects.all() query?

Comment: @101is5: normally it will. But if you do not submit to the `CreateView`, that view will *not* handle the creation of a new user.

Comment: I asked about the email field UserCreationForm because I tried adding a random field in the ModelForm and got an error: FieldError: Unknown field(s) (field) specified for User

Comment: @101is5: the field should be defined on the `User` model you use, so if your user model has no `age` field, then you can not add one to `fields = ...`.

Comment: I've made a few tests here, and I guess the key point gravitates more towards the "submitting to its own view" thing. Thank you for that. To me it seems like a very important but small detail: I don't think I had seen any mention to that until now. Is there anywhere I can find more about it? Is it in the docs?

Comment: @101is5: it is quite common for HTTP servers that the submission of the form is handled by the same view that renders the form. For example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#the-view it says: "*Form data sent back to a Django website is processed by a view, **generally the same view** which published the form. This allows us to reuse some of the same logic.*"

Comment: One last thing(I guess): could you explain the error `BaseForm.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'`?

Comment: @101is5: only a `ModelForm` takes the `instance` parameter. Is it possible you worked with an `UpdateVIew` as well (where the `register` view is pointing to?) https://github.com/django/django/blob/3702819227fd0cdd9b581cd99e11d1561d51cbeb/django/views/generic/edit.py#L116

Comment: I do have an UpdateView set up as well, but 'register' isn't pointing to it. It is actually pointing to another CreateView because I wanted to request first User data, then, at another view, information like full name, address, etc...

Comment: Btw, I guess at this point adding fields to User isn't possible anymore. I should start a new project, right?

Comment: @101is5: there are a few ways to extend the user model: creating a custom one, creating a model with a `OneToOneField`, etc. This section discusses these: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model You do not need to start a new project, you can try to alter the user model, etc. to store the extra data.

Answer (score -2):

when you use **CreateView** on a model, it calls **create** method.

but **User** model is different. User model doesn't have **create**, instead have **create_user**. and **CreateView** doesn't know about it.
i suggest that you use **View** class like this:

```
class UserRegisterView(View):
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    template_name = 'account/register.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('home:home')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            User.objects.create_user(cd['username'], cd['email'], cd['password1'])
            messages.success(request, 'you registered successfully', 'success')
            return redirect('home:home')
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})
```

this snippet totally works.

Comment: I don't know, CreateView seems to be a pretty common practice for adding new users, according to what I've been searching

Comment: A `CreateView` does not call `.create(...)` or at least not directly: it calls `.save()` on the form. Eventually the form can of course call the `.create(...)` method. Furthermore a user manager *does* have a `.create(...)` method, but it will indeed not work properly, since the password should be hashed and the created user object can thus not be used to log in properly.